# How to Display Tool-Tip for the Stacked Bar chart?

Tags: java, jframe, jfreechart, stacked-chart

[image]

I am using Stacked Bar chart and I have plotted Different value in the Stacked Bar chart. 
and I am using tool tip and I can take Single value on the tool tip when I hover mouse on the bar.
using This.

```
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator("<html>Leave Type {0} <br> Month {1} <br> {2} ({3}) <br> Total : {4} </html>", NumberFormat.getInstance()));
```

But for the Total I am not getting proper what I want. because I need Total of that particular bar in the tag of the total. but I am not getting that. please can anybody help me for the same.
I am very much indeed of that.
Thank you for your ans in advance.

Comment: Please show what you are currently "getting" instead of just describing it, as your question is not quite clear what the problem is

Comment: its just like that when u hover bar that should be give Tool tip and that must be having data which is containing into the bar

Comment: and there is Leave Details which is having Different value so i need total of that. on hover. as if into the ToolTip.

Comment: see the update and screen shot and into the tool tip i need the total of the Leave for that particular bar chart.

Comment: Your [screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) is hard to read and `StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator` only defines `{0}…{2}`; please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: if u can download that image and zoom it u can see that clearly that there is tool tip where i am getting some data but m not getting total of the bar that i need.